# Mapping in R: Having trouble moving the text box out of my map

Tags: r, dictionary, colors, mapping, r-markdown

Here is my code:

```
tm_shape(natural)+
  tm_polygons("Name", title = "Proportion of EV Count", palette = "-GnBu",
      legend.hist = T, legend.position=c(0.8, 0.2))+
  tm_compass(position = c(0, 0.07)) +
  tm_layout(frame = T, title = "County EV Proportion", 
      title.size = 0.2, title.position = c(0, "top"), 
      legend.hist.size = 0.5)+tm_text("Name", size = 0.8)
```

Here is the output: How do I move the color box so that it is not right on top of my map?

[image: Adding image]

Comment: Did you want to move the entire legend? You could include `legend.outside = TRUE` to `tm_layout` to put the legend outside of the map. If you're looking for something else, please describe further.

Comment: I am trying to move the entire legend away from my map. I am going to try legend.outside=TRUE

Comment: It is still not working. Now I have this code```{r}
tm_shape(natural)+
  tm_polygons("Name", title = "Proportion of EV Count", palette = "-GnBu", legend.outside=TRUE)+
  tm_compass(position = c(0, 0.07)) +
  tm_layout(frame = F, title = "County EV Proportion", 
      title.size = 0.8, title.position = c(0, "top"), 
      legend.hist.size = 0.5)+tm_text("Name", size = 0.8)
```

Comment: If you could, provide a sample of your data (using `dput()`) to make this reproducible.

Comment: `legend.outside` should go in `tm_layout` not `tm_polygons`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `legend.outside` in `tm_layout`. Here is an example:

```
data(World)

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("economy") +
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE)
```

[image: world may with outside legend]